# SQL sub query WHERE last of id

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Trying my first sub query and cant seem to get the right syntax, tried many variations, not sure if i should use temp table or not. Im using this as a guide:

[Source](http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/)

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE log.user_id = 16)AS tempTable' at line 11

**SQL**

```
UPDATE log 
SET log.out_datetime = NOW() 
WHERE log.log_id IN
(
   SELECT log_id FROM
   (
       SELECT log.log_id 
       FROM log 
       ORDER BY log.log_id DESC
       LIMIT 1 
       WHERE log.user_id = 16 //<- line 11
   )
AS tempTable
)
```

Comment: The `WHERE` goes before the `ORDER BY`

Comment: OMG thanks i'm kinda new to ordering things (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. `WHERE` should come before the `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` clause --

```
UPDATE log 
SET log.out_datetime = NOW() 
WHERE log.log_id IN
(
       SELECT log.log_id 
       FROM log 
       WHERE log.user_id = 16 
       ORDER BY log.log_id DESC
       LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Do you need extra `SUBQUERY` ?

Comment: you are right @minatverma , no need for that I didn't notice it was extra , as in first sight it seemed me of syntax ordering error

Answer (score 0):

Your statements are out of order.  Also, you don't need `IN`, you can just use `=`.

More importantly, you don't need a subquery at all, because MySQL supports `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in `UPDATE` queries:

```
UPDATE log 
    SET log.out_datetime = NOW() 
    WHERE log.user_id = 16 
    ORDER BY log.log_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this...suspecting I was making it to complicated,new to a lot of these SQL syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be change as below.

Correct SQL syntax:
SELECT field-names FROM table-name WHERE field-name=value ORDER BY field-name DESC LIMIT number-of-result

```
UPDATE log 
SET log.out_datetime = NOW() 
WHERE log.log_id IN
(
   SELECT log_id FROM
   (
       SELECT log.log_id 
       FROM log 
       WHERE log.user_id = 16
       ORDER BY log.log_id DESC
       LIMIT 1
   )
AS tempTable
)
```